# How to configure a decimal numeric field for an iOS (iPhone) app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8, uitextfield

I have an app that needs to include a field where the user can input a decimal scalar number. Is there a recipe for how to accomplish this? I've read the relevant parts in Matt Neuburg's "Programming iOS 7" book. I've tried a Cocoapod ([MPNumericTextField](https://github.com/marzapower/MPNumericTextField)). I'm not having a lot of luck...

What I've accomplished so far:

1. Painted a `UITextField` in my storyboard.
2. Given it an `outlet` and a `delegate`.
3. Set its `Keyboard Type` to `Decimal Pad`.
4. Implemented the following 3 methods:

   ```
   - (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
       NSLog(@"textFieldShouldEndEditing:");
       [textField resignFirstResponder];
       return YES;
   }

   - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
       NSLog(@"textFieldShouldReturn:");
       [textField resignFirstResponder];
       return YES;
   }

   - (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
       NSLog(@"textFieldDidBeginEditing:");
       [textField selectAll: nil];
   }
   ```

It appears that I'll have to implement `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` method to avoid duplicate decimal points being put in.

But I can't figure out how to dismiss/close the keyboard when I'm done inputting the number. What's the point of the `Decimal Pad` if you can't close it?

Are there other things I have to do get a simple numeric field working?

Comment: Add an input accessory view with a button and any other controls you want.

Comment: Another option that I've seen several apps use is to put a "Done" button in the nav bar when the keyboard is up.

Comment: [self.view endEditing:YES];  
this will remove keyboard from your view

Comment: I've successfully put the button in the field, and it works to close the keypad. But the user can also interact with other controls, and unless those controls open a new keyboard, the keypad stays up even while working with other controls. Which seems awkward to me.

Answer (score 1):

Following line of code might serve your need

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to implement delegate like this to scan number and avoid double `.` in value.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if (textField == _amountField) {
        NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
        if ([newString length] == 0) 
        {
            return YES;
        }

        double holder;

        NSScanner *scan = nil;

        scan = [NSScanner scannerWithString: newString];

        return ([scan scanDouble: &holder] && [scan isAtEnd]);
    }

    return YES;
}
```